# Detect height change (not resize) in AngularJs directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

First of all, I know there are ways to detect when the screen size change by using:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {...
```

But in my case what happens is a change in the document height because of a `toggle` click I have. So it's not a resize, wich is not firing that event.

Basically I have a div that can be toggled, via `ngClick` and `ngIf`, to show/hide it's cotent. In another area of the view, there is another div, controled by one directive, to apply a dynamic style. For example:

```
<div class="toBeToggle">
    <button ng-click="toggle = !toggle">Toogle</button>
    <p ng-if="!toggle">content to be toggled...</p>
</div>
[... more content ...]
<div class="toBeDynamic">
    <div my-directive>this div has dynamic styles</div>
    [...]
</div>
```

So what I want is to receive/detect when the height change inside `myDirective`, but the toggle click is executed in other element.

I tried this inside `myDirective` (as a desperate/last try - because watch isn't optimal):

```
scope.$watch( '$window.innerHeight', function( new, old ) {
    console.log( 'height change' );
});
```

But also didn't worked. Nothing is detecting the height change. How can I do this?

Comment: can your `slideToggle` function use `$broadcast` or `$emit`?

Comment: @Claies 'yes'. That would be my last try. Currently i can create this toggle by using just `ngClick`, like `toggle = !toggle` and `ngIf`, without the need of a `controller`, `directive`, etc. So I would have to create one just for this purpose. But yeah, if there is no other way, I think I can go with `$broadcast`.

Comment: so why not create a watch on `toggle` then?

Comment: @Claies I tried, but it's not within the directive scope, so it's not detecting it as well. Unless I've been doing this wrong. But i tried just like the innerHeight watch.

Comment: something about what you are describing is missing here.  First you said you use a `slideToggle` function, but then you say you aren't using a function, just `ngIf`.  your code doesn't show any example of the usage at all.  It would be helpful to recreate your issue, but there isn't enough here to create an accurate [mcve].

Comment: @Claies sorry, i didn't made myself clear. I've edited the question, see if it's clear now.

Comment: I believe it's better to fire an event from your slideToggle function. Because if not, you would be $watching height from DOM - it will imply reading from it

Comment: it's still not really clear what your directive definition looks like, but you might have a few other options, like passing `toggle` as a parameter to `myDirective`, or defining `toggle` on `$rootScope`....  I would go with passing it as a parameter, especially since it seems the behavior of the directive is tied to the value.